# CTF Crypto question

Tags: encryption, ctf

The question in a CTF was this:

> They used two hydrogen atoms (H2) from the SHA-256 molecule to encrypt
> in some form of AES, and the result was as follows:
>
> ```
> {mIT+GVt+p0YfgfOltHgqoetTS6h8bRSAScAGKrBE+g8TJfgsjeiX4/tloGU1In9j42l+zlAnI0+hmbgzpOEmKw==}
> ```
>
> If the key length is short, they may have used that key twice

I could not work it out. How to solve this kind of question?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Implying you know the flag format you could use the magic module in CyberChef.

Comment: two hydrogen atoms ... https://github.com/jedisct1/libhydrogen ?